# Connotation of "cancer" for native speaker

Tags: connotation

I am a German native speaker. I'm planning a new blog and trying to figure out the best name. I would like to name the blog "three little cancers" in reference to our surname which is "Krebs" (meaning cancer in English) but I am not sure about the connotation for english native speaker. Because, if I hear the word cancer, the first thing that comes to my mind is the disease.

How is it for native speaker? Do you think about the animal or the disease if you hear/read the word "cancer"?

Comment: When I read the term *cancer* it reminds me of the breast cancer which killed my friend nearly a year ago.

Comment: I'd think that most native speakers would assume you were referring to the disease(s).

Comment: The standard word for the sea creature is **crab**, like your **Krebs**. _Cancer_ is used _only_ for the disease (or the Latin name for the creature).

Comment: The only time we use the word *cancer* to mean *crab* is when we talk about the astrological sign. And if you're talking about the zodiac, you need to capitalize the word *Cancer*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German word *krebs* can refer to the animals *crabs* or the disease *cancer*. In English the word *crab* refers to just the animal. The word *cancer* refers in normal usage mainly to the disease, but sometimes to the astrological sign. The word *cancer* cannot be used to refer to the animal in every day usage.

For these reasons, *The Three Little Crabs* would be a suitable title, but the version with the disease would clearly not.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So i had the misunderstanding that because "cancer"also refers to the astrological sign it would automatically refer the animal as well. With that knowledge I will certainly name the blog "Three little crabs" ;) Thanks

Comment: Any feedback on the downvote? Can't improve the post without it!